# Stroke small text in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I would like to narrow some small black text, where
the fill is black and the stroke is white in order to make the text look thinner.

The font's sizes are from 3-6 pt. The stroke I use is 0.005pt.
When saving the file in PDF, the fonts looks too bright. How can I fix this?

Comment: That stroke is way too fine to make any difference. Any change that you are seeing is almost certainly just the screen preview. If you can share some screenshots then we may be able to help.

Comment: The thinnest practical line weight (a hairline) is ¼ point (0.0035 inches). Thinner than that will not print reliably.

Answer (score 4):

While you *can* bully the appearance of a heavier or lighter face by applying a stroke, it's almost always a bad idea. However, at 3 to 6pt size, it's a very bad idea.

Text that small is going to be almost unreadable for many people. You'll need the best rendering you can get from the font to have any success. Stroking the text to affect a faux weight is a mistake.

If an already lighter version of your font does not exist, use a different, lighter face altogether.